# pagination Laravel Scout search: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination, laravel-scout

hi and thanks for replies.
i use : [laravel-scout-mysql-driver](https://github.com/YABhq/laravel-scout-mysql-driver) to index and search mysql database. according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898321/mysql-error-is-thrown-when-laravel-pagination-is-used) set: `'strict'=>false` the code:

```
   public function searchpages(Request $request){

    $query= $request->get('query');
    $adpgs=[];
    $pages= \App\Page::search("*".$query."*")->paginate(1);
    return view('content.pages_show')->with(['pages'=>$pages,'adpgs'=>$adpgs]);


}
```

provides pagination links correctly, but when click on links, the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `pages` where MATCH(en_id,fa_id,title,subtitle,address,phones,mobiles,brf_work_hours,moreinfo) AGAINST(**qqq** IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

is shown. Why and what i most do???

Comment: try this `$pages= \App\Page::search('%' . $query . '%')->paginate(1);`

Comment: thanks alot; it works! but why? and please answer to accept